# How to extract IP address from given tuple with mix of string and integer number

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

i have one tuple and i want to extract IP address(**192.168.0.1**) and '**Hello**' message from given tuple which is mixed of string and number

a=(b'Hello',('192.168.0.1',34343))

plz help how i can do using python code?

Comment: `a[1][0]` is the IP address in this particular case - are all of your tuples in this exact format?

Comment: Is this a regex question even? I don't see any parsing that is required. Can't you access the tuple using indexes like `a[0]` for 'Hello' and `a[1][0]` for IP?

Comment: @jasonharper Exact format is :

(b'Hello', ('192.168.0.1', 34343))

this message is receiving from remote PC. I want to get Hello and IP address

Comment: `text, ip = a[0], a[1][0]`

Comment: @Krypt1 Yes this regex question 
for string type data, it is easy to get any number or character but this is mixed of string and number 
i mean IP is string type in tuple and port number is not string 
Can you tell me how i can extract from this tuple 
(b'Hello', ('192.168.0.1', 34343))
I want to extract Hello and IP address

Comment: If it's a tuple, then you can just use indexes as it's pointed out in other comments / answer. If this doesn't work for you, then please provide an [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your message, use:
   `a[0]`
To get your IP, use:
`a[1][0]`
To get 34343 (whatever that is), use: `a[1][1]`